# How to make subview's position change relate to its superview?Using storyboard's auto layout

Tags: ios, storyboard, autolayout

when I use old AutosizingMask, I got this
[image: old]
but when switch to new AutoLayout, it seems that I must set an/muti edge of screen, but actually I need none of them.
Why I need this is I want to use just one storyboard to adapt both iphone3.5/4 and ipad,
is there any solution to solve this or achieve my purpose?
thx :)

Comment: enable the all positions in AutoSizing.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding correctly you want the red square to grow if the container grows.

So for that you would add fixed user constraints to the top, left, bottom and top of a fixed value.

I would recommend using a different Storyboard for the iPad thought because you could preview the changes is Interface Builder.